# Port of Entry travelling from Toronto (Pearson) to US?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, airports, yyz, pre-clearance

I'm travelling from Pearson airport (YYZ) in Toronto to the US with a TN Visa application, which I'll need to bring to the "US port of entry." Will that be at my destination in the US, or does it happen right at Pearson? I know that other US customs/immigration activities happen at Pearson, before you ever leave Canada, so I'm not sure if this does too.

I ask because I need to plan how early to be at the airport: 2 hours for security, or 4 ours for security + immigration?

Answer (score 5):

You will be passing the US immigration in Toronto, before boarding. That will be your "port of entry", and they'll have to be the ones to approve your TN status. Plan your time accordingly.